# How do I print a variable in a Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, variables

I have been trying to find out a way to print a variable in a windows forms application and I can't find a way. I cant console write it, or print it in any way normally. (this is my second time using windows forms applications) this is kind of what I'm trying to do.
`DataGridView.Write(Book1.title + Book1.author + Book1.pages);` etc.
Any help would be nice, thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Could you please expand on what you are attempting to do, with perhaps a little note about what you have tried so far.  Thankyou.

Comment: Where do you want to *print* a variable ? A console, a label, a textbox, a messagebox... ? What do you mean by **print** ? DataGridView is for displaying tabular data like in Excel: do you want to change the content of a cell ?

Comment: I want to print the value of a variable into a label.

Comment: If you debug the program (Debug > Start Debugging) then console messages will be visible in the Visual Studio output window (Debug > Windows > Output). Otherwise, just set the Text property on a label.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are using WinFroms and trying to print a variable on screen (set label text), do following

1. Add a label on the form
2. Set Text property to that variable

i.e. If your label ID is lblOutput and variable is an integer name v, code will be following

```
lblOutput.Text = v.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, when I build it with the code it doesn't print, it just stays blank. Was I supposed to write anything in the label text box?

Comment: Please share your code. Without code it is difficult to help you.